# Trouble importing commands with Beanshell

Tags: java, beanshell

I can't seem to import the commands from one Beanshell script to another. I keep getting "Error in script callingScript Command not found: helloWorld()"

Here's my calling script:

```
// c:/myProjectDir/bsh/callingScript.bsh

...
addClassPath("/bsh"); // My default directory is myProjectDir
importCommands("utils");
helloWorld();
```

And my called script:

```
// c:/myProjectDir/bsh/utils/HelloWorld.bsh

helloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

When I print out the classpath right before running importCommands I get:

```
Classpath: 
... (random jars) 
file:/C:/myProjectDir/bsh/
```

I've seen beanshell documentation and other resources that all show something like this and seem to work. I just can't figure out what I'm doing differently (read: wrong) which is preventing the import from happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't have a method within the classes that I was trying to import that were the same as my file names.

So in the example in the question, I had a file named "HelloWorld.bsh" and a method named "helloWorld()". Simply renaming the method to "HelloWorld()" (capitalized to match filename) fixed the issue.